# When does down vote cost you a point?

Tags: discussion, support, downvotes

Just out of curiosity: I down-voted a post and it appeared that it did cost me a point: [image: down vote]

What I don't understand: when does SO do that? I had other down-votes which did not seem to cost anything. Or was I just dreaming in the past?

Comment: Oh, I see. That got me two down-votes immediately.

Comment: Yeah. For lack of research. Not that you lost any rep, mind.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down - yes, information that you can trivially look up in the help center does lead to quick question downvotes on meta. But those don't influence your rep...

Comment: Sometimes you don't find it although you searched. Well, the answer came swiftly :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I down-voted a post and it appeared that it did cost me a point:

Please see the [downvoting privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) link.

**What happens when I vote down?**

When you vote down, you are nudging that content "down" the page, so it will be seen by fewer people. Voting down answers is not something we want you to take lightly, so it is not free.

- Downvotes remove 2 reputation from the post owner.
- Downvotes on answers remove 1 reputation from you, the voter.
- Downvotes on questions are free.
- You can vote 30 times per UTC day. You get an additional 10 votes on
  questions only

Answer (score 4):

When you downvote an answer on a main Q&A site (not an attached meta site).

See [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) for details.

Comment: Lol - I could down-vote you for posting a link-only answer, but I dont ;-) Thanks for the link.

Comment: It isn't a link only. I gave the complete answer in the first sentence. And you are welcome to downvote - won't effect your or my reputation - as my answer states.

Comment: You're all professionals here and I'm just a rookie.

Comment: No one said that. You said this was a link only answer. I contest that.

Comment: Your username is a link @Oded, ima downvote your name :@